# Ember.js: how to analyze error in vendor.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've deployed my ember-cli app in stage environment to let teammates test the app. In the app I have implemented `Ember.onerror` to email me errors that occur in stage and in production environment.

```
Ember.onerror = function(data) {
    Ember.$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url + "/error",
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({message: data.message, stacktrace: data.stack}),
      beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', settings.accepts.json);
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm having difficulties in analyze stacktrace because it references only vendor.js and I can't understand where the problem really is.

For example I've received following message:

`Message: Nothing handled the action 'back'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.`

and stacktrace:

```
EmberError@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:25705:26 
triggerEvent@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:38985:44 
trigger@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:64971:26 
trigger@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:63740:21 
send@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:38468:45 
send@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:42710:26 
runRegisteredAction@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:33277:30 
run@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:10765:30 
run@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:30030:32 
handler@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:33269:39 
http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:55210:34 
dispatch@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:4872:14 
handle@http://example.com/assets/vendor-952b195e45ab9682c02f1fabba312c19.js:4540:33
```

The meaning of the error message is clear, but I'm wondering if there's a way to easily recognize where that `back` action is not handled.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299475/153911