# ember.js: how to debug based on assets/vendor-*.js

Tags: javascript, debugging, ember.js

This is more of a general question, but I imagine others have encountered this problem as well -- see for instance this SO question: [Ember.js: how to analyze error in vendor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273979/ember-js-how-to-analyze-error-in-vendor-js?rq=1)

I am working on a larger Ember-based application, where, if errors occur, I sometimes get rather cryptic stack traces, similar to this sample:

```
TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
at e.func (https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:13:6039)
at e.get (https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:11:29357)
at Object.o [as isPath] (https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:13:5640)
at Object.u [as set] (https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:13:10630)
at n.set (https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:16:725)
at n.cancel (https://XXX/assets/YYY-707bc84342df7a5350ea91fcc2b9bf53.js:1:20788)
at o.join (https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:7:6400)
at Function.u.join (https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:13:12315)
at https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:9:30923
at Object.h [as flaggedInstrument] (https://XXX/assets/vendor-c3ea8aab9a11f79411cf3b32532ea544.js:12:18911)
```

Since everything refers to /assets/vendor-*.js files, it is very laborious to find out exactly where the error has occurred.

At the moment, I try to deduce where the error has occurred based on the endpoint accessed and my knowledge of the software. However, this is highly unreliable and unstructured, since the errors are very often highly vague, given the size of my code base.

For instance here, it is obvious that an object on which indexOf() is called (presumably an array) is probably undefined or null and, as such, calling indexOf() on it doesn't work, hence the error. But guess how many arrays use indexOf() in a couple of hundred large-ish source files ;-)

Is there a better, more structured approach that I can use to debug in such situations?

Comment: Usually the error originates from your code.
See if you can trace out using (debuggers, try/catch) which part of your code leads to these errors.

Comment: @yuvraj zohan If I knew where to trace out, I wouldn't be asking here, since my question would be answered :-) We are talking about hundreds of source code files. Furthermore, these are bugs that have occurred in a running test system, and often it's quite hard to replicate them. Being able to narrow down where I am searching would be really helpful. This is why I am curious if there is a better way.

Comment: Use the dev environment for debugging, not the prod environment. Then you won't have minified code, and some extra debug code enabled. This should give you a better start.

Comment: The `YYY-707bc84342df7a5350ea91fcc2b9bf53.js` looks like it may be a minified file of your app. Maybe you can 'click' into it and use pritify option in developers' tool of the browser?

Comment: @Cristina From the information you have provided, it is very difficult to guess what is the problem. To narrow down your problem as `Lux` said use the dev environment. And follow these:
1) Trace which route the error occurs at (hopefully this does not happen in all the routes)
2) If you have multiple components in that route find where this one comes from.
3) Check if the error comes from calls to the external libraries you have used.
And of course spend more time on the problem, and debug by narrowing problem at each step.

Comment: Good suggestions, thank you everyone! The problem is that often this is all the information I am getting (these are automatically reported bugs that have occurred at some time in the past).  This is why I was wondering if there is some way to milk more information out of the vendor-*.js assets.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to see the library js file used by putting 'pause on exceptions' in chromium debugger and checking what's the library that has the line of failure. After that, you may change the library reference in ember-cli-build.js from libraryx.js to libraryx.src.js or equivalent for the particular library.